# Facet field value return same value multiple time with anagram

Tags: java, solr, solrj, facet

I am trying to get the unique values for a field from solr. I have used facet to get the field values. My facet query param looks like-

```
        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
        query.setQuery("*:*");
        query.setFacet(true);
        query.addFacetField("division");
```

I am printing the facet value using-

```
resp = solrClient.query(query);

            List<FacetField> fflist = resp.getFacetFields();
            for(FacetField ff : fflist){
                String ffname = ff.getName();

                int ffcount = ff.getValueCount();

                System.out.println(ffname+" "+ffcount);
                List<Count> counts = ff.getValues();
                for(Count c : counts){
                    String facetLabel = c.getName();
                    long facetCount = c.getCount();

                    System.out.println("facetlabel-->"+facetLabel+" facetcount-->"+facetCount);
                }
            }
```

I am getting following response for this-

```
facetlabel-->seirossecca facetcount-->184
facetlabel-->accessori facetcount-->184
facetlabel-->seirossecca facetcount-->184
facetlabel-->cinht facetcount-->116
facetlabel-->cinht facetcount-->116
facetlabel-->ethnic facetcount-->116
facetlabel-->spot facetcount-->851
facetlabel-->spot facetcount-->851
facetlabel-->top facetcount-->851
facetlabel-->raewtoof facetcount-->577
facetlabel-->footwear facetcount-->577
facetlabel-->raewtoof facetcount-->577
facetlabel-->smottob facetcount-->387602
facetlabel-->bottom facetcount-->387602
facetlabel-->smottob facetcount-->387602
facetlabel-->ytuaeb facetcount-->354158
facetlabel-->beauti facetcount-->354158
facetlabel-->ytuaeb facetcount-->354158
facetlabel-->scinortcel facetcount-->204244
facetlabel-->electron facetcount-->204244
facetlabel-->scinortcel facetcount-->204244
facetlabel-->sesserd facetcount-->161
facetlabel-->dress facetcount-->161
facetlabel-->sesserd facetcount-->161
```

As you can see I am getting the anagram of faceted field with separate entries but the corresponding field value is same. Division is of type-

> text_search

Text search definition in schema.xml is of-

```
<fieldType name="text_search" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true" multiValued="true">
        <analyzer type="index">
          <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnNumerics="0" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>
          <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
          <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnNumerics="0" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>
          <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: I think it is because of the fieldType applied for the division field...COuld you please share the fieldType used for the field division...

Comment: Field type for division is ArrayList.

Comment: Check it in your schema.xml...search for the field division and check what fieldType is used? Check what type of analyser it contains?

Comment: its <field name="division" type="text_search" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

Comment: I need the details of the fieldType "text_search"...? like whats analyzer and tokenizer and filter it has ...how it is been built up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109036/discussion-between-abhijit-bashetti-and-y0gesh-gupta).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using `ReversedWildcardFilterFactory`.

`ReversedWildcardFilterFactory` : A filter that reverses tokens.

Same is happening for you..

`seirossecca` is the reverse of `accessories`
and `accessories` is shortened to `accessori` because of `PorterStemFilterFactory` as it removes common endings from words.

To avoid this you can remove `ReversedWildcardFilterFactory` from you `schema.xml`.

```
PorterStemFilterFactory :
```

is left to you if want if to remove common endings from words.